# Can't pull up user info right after entered in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I have a register form with an indexedDB. I have resgister/log in working. I've been trying different things to get a new register to login as soon as they register but im not sure what's going. It won't work. The localStorage sets like it should but it won't bring up the user's data.

JS:

```
function addObject(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to resgister?')){
     fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
     lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
     userName = document.getElementById('uName').value;
     pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
     email = document.getElementById('email').value;
     dob = document.getElementById('dob').value;
     tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;
     bio = document.getElementById('bio').value;
     terms = document.getElementById('terms').value;
     school = document.getElementById('school').value;

     //Need loop to find radio button values
     radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');
     for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            gender=radios[i].value;
        }
     }

        //set up transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 

        //get object store
        var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 

        //Add item
        var request = myusers.put(new getUser(userName,fName,lName,pass,email,dob,tel,bio,terms,school,gender));
    }

    // Show all results.
    if(document.URL.indexOf('admin.html') > -1){
        mytransaction.addEventListener('complete', showUsers);  
    } 

    //Log in new users
    loginCheck(userName,pass);
    /*newLocal('user',user); */
    //Reset Form Fields
    resetForm(); 

}
```

This is the functions I use when someone logs in.

```
function loginCheck(user,pass){    
db.transaction("users").objectStore("users").get(user).onsuccess = function(e) {
    var loggedUser = e.target.result;
        if(!loggedUser){
            alert('Sorry, Username does not exist. Please try again.');
        }else if(pass !== loggedUser.pw ){
            alert('Incorrect log in combination. Please try again.');
            }else{
                loggedIn(loggedUser);
                populateFields(loggedUser);
                loginStyle(loggedUser)
                }        
    }    
}
function loggedIn(loggedUser){
    var u=loggedUser;
    alert('Welcome '+u.fn+' '+u.ln+' to Macroplay');       

    //Set localStorage     
    var signedin = 'user';
    var username = u.userName;
    newLocal(signedin,username);
}
function getValues(){ 
db.transaction("users").objectStore("users").get(localStorage.user).onsuccess = function(e) { 
    populateFields(e.target.result); 
    loginStyle(e.target.result)
    }; 
    ;
}
```

From what I can see the first part adds the user to the DB and the second portion should behave as is I was just logging normally. But it won't pull up the info from the DB.

I've tried setting the new user to localStorage which is how I recognize a user currently loggedin but that also had no effect.

This is my site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `onsuccess` handler in the `loginCheck` method, but you're not when calling `put` on the db. My guess would be that you're checking to see if the user exists before it's actually had a chance to be added. Try this:

```
//Add item
var request = myusers.put(new getUser(userName,fName,lName,pass,email,dob,tel,bio,terms,school,gender));
request.onsuccess = function () {

    // Show all results.
    if(document.URL.indexOf('admin.html') > -1){
        mytransaction.addEventListener('complete', showUsers);  
    } 

    //Log in new users
    loginCheck(userName,pass);
    /*newLocal('user',user); */
    //Reset Form Fields
    resetForm(); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me error that the user isn't in the DB and when I check my DB in the consol the user key is there but the object is null. I tried change onsuccess to oncomplete but that didn't help either